# ConTeXt: How to keep title and table of contents on the same page

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking, context

How can I tell ConTeXt not to insert a page break before `\completecontent`? I'm trying to keep `A title` on the same page as the table of contents:

```tex
\starttext

  \startfrontmatter
    A title
    \completecontent
  \stopfrontmatter

  \startbodymatter

    \startchapter [title=Foo]
    \stopchapter

  \stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\completecontent` command uses `\title` to place the the title for the table of contents. To get rid of the pagebreak at the start of it you can either disable the pagebreak with

```
\setuphead
  [title]
  [page=no]
```

but this isn't recommended because the setting affects all `\title` commands. While it is possible to limit the setup to the `frontmatter` a better solution is to create a new heading

```
\definehead
  [contenttitle]
  [title]
```

and disable the pagebreak onl for this heading

```
\setuphead
  [contenttitle]
  [page=no]
```

The next is is to remove the `\completecontent` command from your document and replace it with a combination of the new heading followed by a table of contents without the automatic title.

```
\contenttitle{\headtext{content}}
\placecontent
```

With `\headtext{content}` you can access the language dependant title for the table of contents but there is nothing wrong to set a fixed text instead (`\contenttitle{Contents}`).

Answer (score 0):

Although it isn't perfectly explicit about this, the Wiki (https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Table_of_Contents) suggests the following:

```
\completecontent % with title
\placecontent % without title
```

You should find that replacing `\completecontent` with `\placecontent` will do the trick.

Comment: I know but as you pointed out `\placecontent` gets rid of the title. I want to keep the title but remove the page break.

Comment: The title for `\completecontent` is placed with the `\title` command which forces a pagebreak with the default settings. While you can disable the pagebreak it is better to create a new heading (e.g. `\definehead [contenttitle] [title]`) where you disable it (e.g. `\setuphead [contenttitle] [page=no]`). Afterwards you can use `\contenttitle{\headtext[content]}` followed by `\placecontent` to flush the table of contents.

Comment: @noibe I guess I assumed that since you were already providing "A title" in your example, then the title provided by `\placecontent` would be extraneous... But seems like Wolfgang has already offered a more complete solution